# correct way to upload image to database

Tags: php, database, blob

i know some of you are going to say that this isnt the correct way but im on a tight deadline to finish an application and as of now i cant go back and modify the code to store the images  in a directory.

now that thats cleared

the question i had is i inserted an image into the database by typing this.

(dont mind the class security call, all that is doing is a few checks if the data is valid)

```
$filename = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['name']);
$tmpname = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['tmp_name']);
$imgsize = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['size']);
$imgtype = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['type']);
$school = $security->secure($_POST['school']);


//begin upload
if($imgsize > 0) {
$handle = fopen($tmpname, "r");
$content = fread($handle, filesize($tmpname));
$content = addslashes($content);

//code to add all this to database
}
```

the variable $content is the image and all its getting is the addslashes. i remember someone once mentioning to do it with something called base64 but i can barely recall how it was written.

this is how i am calling the image from the database

aside from all the queries and whatnot
this is the main part that is calling the image

```
header("Content-length: ".$imgsize);
header("Content-type: ".$imgtype);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$imgname);
print $row['img'];
```

the problem i am having is that instead of the image showing. the url is only showing, so in this case i only see this

http://localhost/admin/school-catalog.php?page=gallery&id=4

when opening the page to view the image with the correct params set in the url.

---

for those that wanted to see the query that is being done to save the image and so forth
i copied the whole section

```
//save image to db
if(isset($_POST['btnupload'])) {

$filename = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['name']);
$tmpname = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['tmp_name']);
$imgsize = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['size']);
$imgtype = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['type']);
$school = $security->secure($_POST['school']);


//begin upload
if($imgsize > 0) {
$handle = fopen($tmpname, "r");
$content = fread($handle, filesize($tmpname));
$content = base64_encode($content);
}

$save = mysql_query("insert into tbl_schoolgallery(id,hash,img,imgtype,imgsize) values(null,'$school','$content','$imgtype','$imgsize')") or die(mysql_error());
header("Location: school-catalog.php?page=school_gallery");

}


//call image from db
$query = mysql_query("select * from $tbl where id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

$imgtypeget = explode("/", $row['imgtype']);

$imgname = "img.".$imgtypeget[1];
$imgtype = $row['imgtype'];
$imgsize = $row['imgsize'];

header("Content-length: ".$imgsize);
header("Content-type: ".$imgtype);
print base64_decode($row['img']);

print $row['img'];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using print $content?

Comment: i cant because im calling the image from the database

Comment: That part of the code and a data sample is missing then, are you sure that the img column contains the proper value?

Comment: Could we see your queries to insert and read from the database? I have a feeling your bug is in there.

Comment: Is Content-Disposition needed for displaying a file?

Comment: Content-Disposition is used to set the downloaded file name (say, if you were sending the user a Word document and wanted a default value when their Save As... prompt shows up). When used correctly in this case, it would make it so going directly to the image URL would force a download rather than displaying.

Comment: I think you'll find that localhost link is only going to work on your machine :)

Comment: While storing binary data in an SQL database has problems, it makes sense if you care about transactions (try syncing up the file system with the sql backend), scalability (plenty of tools to help with that for RDMS), backups (why write/use yet another backup system?), and *especially* the interplay of all these issues.

Comment: the content disposition part i didnt really need. i just had forgotten to take it out.

Answer (score 7):

Using `addslashes` is extremely incorrect. Depending on whether your column is a TEXT field or a BLOB field, you should use Base64 or `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Using Base64 isn't that hard; you may as well use that way. Just replace `addslashes` with `base64_encode` and echo the image with `base64_decode`.

There's a bit easier way to write the whole thing, for that matter:

```
// begin upload
if ($imgsize > 0)
{
  $content = file_get_content($tmpname);
  $content = base64_encode($content);
}
```

And then to output you really only need to do

```
header("Content-type: ".$imgtype);
echo base64_decode($img);
```

If the column is a BLOB, however, you can directly use `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
// begin upload
if ($imgsize > 0)
{
  $content = file_get_content($tmpname);
  $content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
}
```

And then:

```
header("Content-type: ".$imgtype);
echo $img;
```

Although judging from your current symptoms, I'm guessing you also have a bug relating to how your image is being stored and recalled from the database, and I'd need to see that part of the code where you make the queries to insert and read from the database before I could help you fix that part.

---

Your current code seems mostly fine. A few issues:

```
print base64_decode($row['img']);

print $row['img'];
```

You probably meant to get rid of the second row. Also, you should use `echo` instead of `print`; everyone uses it, it can be slighty faster sometimes, and `print` doesn't really have any benefit other than returning a value:

```
echo base64_decode($row['img']);
```

`$security->secure()` appears to be some sort of sanitization function. Just use `mysql_real_escape_string()` - that's the one you're supposed to use. Except `$imgsize`; you might want to use `intval()` on that one since you know it's supposed to be an integer.

Also here:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from $tbl where id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

You name the table `tbl_schoolgallery` a few rows above that. I assume `$tbl == 'tbl_schoolgallery'`, but for consistency, you should either use `$tbl` in both places or `tbl_schoolgallery` in both places.

Also, replace that `while` with an `if` - your code would cause trouble if it ever loops more than once, anyway.

Comment: i added the blob of code :p can you review it. thank you for your time.

Comment: i have a feeling this is where the error is at: $tmpname = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['tmp_name']);

what the class is doing is its trowing a value trough mysql_real_escape_string and htmlencode. so the temporary image file is going through that which destroys it lol. funny thing is im using a 3rd party database viewer and im able to see the image clearly inside the databse.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to secure $tmpname.