# Pass image to database in PHP

Tags: php

How can pass the image in database in php?

Comment: I formatted your question. But you have to provide more info.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Or at least coherent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [correct way to upload image to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047547/correct-way-to-upload-image-to-database)

Answer (score 3):

Declare a field in the database as `BLOB`

Read the file with `fread`, escape it with the database-appropriate escape_string function, then store it like any other string.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a two fields in DB (file_name, md5_file). File dispose on server. If you add to DB a row with new photo, you check hash of new file, and compare him with DB's hash. And it is very good to rename photo_file to unique name.