# Upload images using a folder in php

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I have a folder with full of images.But I have to upload the images to mysql database.

How can I do it using php code?

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: Maybe read first: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: Almost duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047547/correct-way-to-upload-image-to-database

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not a good idea to do this. Read the discussion I linked to in the comment.

But to answer your question, [here](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql/2) is what seems to be a pretty complete tutorial showing how to store images in a mySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not store image in DB. It is a bad practice. If we have a some ID, we rename images as image$ID.ext. If we haven't ID, we write in DB only a filename. If you want to write in database all filenames of dir, try to use this code:

```
function getDirectoryList ($directory) {
   $results = array();
   $handler = opendir($directory);
   while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         $results[] = $file;
      }
   }
   closedir($handler);
   return $results;
}
```